How to merge multiple CSV/Excel files into a single file with Python inserting the first column 1 as the CSV file name?
Trying to merge >100 CSV files into a singular Excel file with the following conditions:
Specific rows of the CSV files. (The data contained is from rows 1-250)
first column of the dataframe Excel file is the name of the CSV file.
1-100 CSVs.  Data is contained in rows 1-250. Columns are mostly the same, some CSVs have additional column data.
Desired Output:
1 Excel sheet with all the CSV data starting in column 2 and column one being the name of the CSV file (e.g. data1.csv, data2.csv for the applicable rows).
Current output is the correct merge but column 1 is not populating.
# importing the required modules
import glob
import pandas as pd

 
df = pd.DataFrame()

# specifying the path to csv files
path = "C:/Users/Staylor/Documents/Python test"
 
# csv files in the path
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
 
# list of excel files we want to merge.
# pd.read_excel(file_path) reads the csv
# data into pandas dataframe.
excl_list = []
 
for file in file_list:
    excl_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))
    df['col1'] = file
    
    
# create a new dataframe to store the 
# merged excel file.
excl_merged = pd.DataFrame()
 
for excl_file in excl_list:
     
    # appends the data into the excl_merged 
    # dataframe.
    excl_merged = excl_merged.append(
      excl_file, ignore_index=True)
 
# exports the dataframe into excel file with
# specified name.
excl_merged.to_excel('total_python.xlsx', index=False)



The way how you are trying to add the file name into the first column df['col1']= file isn't correct.

for file in file_list:
    excl_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))
    df['col1'] = file


That's why it's not placing the name into the first column as you wanted.
Here is the updated code as you wanted:

import glob
import pandas as pd

path = "C:/Users/Staylor/Documents/Python test"
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df_list = []

for file in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(file).iloc[:250, :]
    df.insert(0, 'File Name', file.split('/')[-1])
    df_list.append(df)

excel_merged = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
excel_merged.to_excel('total_python.xlsx', index=False)


Firstly, the line df['col1'] = file in your first for loop has several issues.  The first is it is being run after you've appended the file to the list excl_list.  Not only that, but df is an empty dataframe that you define at the start of your code, and then do not use, so this column is not being added to each file at all.  I suggest re-writing your first for loop as follows:
excl_list = []
 
for file in file_list:
    #read in the file as df
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    #add file name as col1
    df['col1'] = file
    #add this dataframe to the list
    excl_list.append(df)

(NB: If you wanted 'col1' to be in the first position in each data frame, use df.insert(loc=0 column='col1', value=file) instead)
The second thing is your second for loop is a really clumsy and inefficient way of combining these dataframes together. Pandas has a pd.concat() function, which can be used to join a list of dataframes together into one.  I would suggest using this, so your code would be:
import pandas as pd

# specifying the path to csv files
path = "C:/Users/Staylor/Documents/Python test"
 
# csv files in the path
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
 
# list of excel files we want to merge.
# pd.read_excel(file_path) reads the csv
# data into pandas dataframe.
excl_list = []
 
for file in file_list:
    #read in the file as df
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    #ad file name as col1
    df['col1'] = file
    #add this dataframe to the list
    excl_list.append(df)
#concat list of files into one dataframe
excl_merged = pd.concat(excl_list, ignore_index=True)

# exports the dataframe into excel file with
# specified name.
excl_merged.to_excel('total_python.xlsx', index=False)
   

